# join two operating system by virtual box

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-7

I have the windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. 
So, can I join them using Virtual Box or any other software which help me go from one OS to another without restarting?!!

thanks for your answer

Comment: I suggest KVM rather then virtualbox, you can not easily boot your windows install with either.

Comment: **Please clarify what you mean.** It *looks* like you have a dual-boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, but since you did not specify that in your question, we as a community can't help you yet. Please add additional information to your question.